# Can't create a log file in java

Tags: java, jsp, logging

Hi° I need to create a log file for my java application but I am unable to do it. I am working on Windows with Netbeans and this is the code:

```
public class Logger {
    public static final java.util.logging.Logger logger;
    static {
        try {
        boolean append = true;
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("log.txt", append);
            fh.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
            logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("log");
            logger.addHandler(fh);
            logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error al inicializar el logger. " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());  
        }
    }
```

}

And this is how I write in the log file:

```
 Logger.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error en ejecucion de SQL: '{}'", ex);
```

I am making a call to my logger class in a jsp file, but the log file is never created. I find it weird because I have the exactly same code in other project and works fine. I am starting to believe it could be something about jsp..
Ideas? Please

Comment: Your code works fine. The file is in the working directory. See `System.getProperty("user.dir")`

Comment: Ok I see it! :P
 I did not specified a directory, so the file was created in the Apache folder how silly!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create log file pro-grammatically.

Simply add `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file in your project's class-path and it is automatically created by log4j.

Use  [Apache log4j™](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) logging for better performance.

Its better explained under [Using Log4j 2 in Web Applications](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) *Apache Log4j Manual*

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("log");
```

to:

```
logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(this);
```

Comment: Tried but still can't create the log file